# Onsubmit URL Redirection with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for best way to do Onsubmit URL Redirection.

Currently I have form like this...

```
<form action="dologin.php?" method="post" id="frmlogin">    
<input type="hidden" value="something" />    
<input type="submit" value="go" />
```

Currently this **dologin.php** is directing me to **clientarea.php**

I cant make any changes in **dologin.php** as it is encoded.

I want me to redirect to **clientdetails.php** as soon as button is clicked.

How can I achieve ?

**Thanks**

**UPDATE**

Currently How I do this....

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function redirect() {
            window.location.href = '/clientarea.php?action=details';
        }
</script>


<form action="dologin.php?" onsubmit="setTimeout('redirect()', 1000);" method="post" id="frmlogin">    
<input type="hidden" value="something" />    
<input type="submit" value="go" />
```

This Do my purpose, Even if login credentials fails it stick to login page with defining errors.

I was just looking for if there is any better/another way of doing it.

Comment: I hope someone else can understand what you are asking because I can't.

Comment: You might be able to send the data via Ajax and then redirect to the other site.

Comment: I'm puzzled: do you want to post the form to dologin.php or to clientdetails.php? Second, is this really your own form or are you trying to get past a login script on some website?

Comment: @zwip - This is not going to help him get past a login script, whatever his purposes are...

Comment: I am not trying to get past a login.. I am at this stage because my dologin.php is encoded..

Comment: Regarding the update: Due to a race condition, what that does depends on your (or the users) luck. Either the form will post normally and the JavaScript is never executed because it's gone after the submit, or the JavaScript will execute before doLogin.php can properly execute, or maybe both will happen. You still haven't clearly said what you want to achieve. Currently I understand that you want to go to clientarea.php even though doLogin.php doesn't allways redirect there, is that right? If yes, where does it go it it doesn't go to clientarea.php?

Comment: @MANnDAaR: Why can you not modify dologin.php? What do you mean by "it's encoded"? *Everything* is encoded. Is it encoded in UTF and you can only handle ASCII? Use a different tool to modify it. Is it encoded in base64? Decode it.

Comment: @ RoToRa: You are correct that its race....That is why I am looking for better solution....& On login it goes to clientarea.php by default but I want to go to clientdetails.php

  
@ Randolpho : PHP Files are Ioncube encoded.

Comment: @MANnDAaR: I replied to your comment with an edit to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Modify the form action to read as such:

```
<form action="clientdetails.php" method="post"> <!-- etc. -->
```

Bam your form now posts directly to clientdetails.php.

Now, if you want to submit to dologin.php and then move to clientdetails.php, perhaps because dologin.php does some processing that you want, you're out of luck; there's no way you can do a redirect client-side without making sure that the submission to dologin.php returns the correct javascript to redirect to the desired URL. Of course, you'd be better off making dologin.php send an HTTP redirect instead, but if you are dead-set on doing it with javascript, you can do it that way.

But either way, you *have* to modify dologin.php.

**Edit:**

> @ Randolpho : PHP Files are Ioncube encoded.
>   – MANnDAaR

So you're trying to hack a third party PHP application that is obfuscated to prevent hacking? I'd approach the PHP application developers to see if they have some mechanism for specifying the redirect. Most login forms allow you to pass the destination URL as a query string parameter. You might even be able to glean the format from your web logs without bothering the developers.

Either way, you should clearly indicate that you're working with third-party code in your question. We can't help you solve your problem without sufficient information.

Comment: I have already approached them about this specific function. But right now they don't support this.

Comment: @MANnDAaR: you are in for a very tough work week. I think the AJAX suggestion by @Felix Kling may be your best route.